# Jenkins: Bypass Shell Variable validation when not set

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have conditionally set Jenkins parameter to read USER_INPUT_VALUE based on upstream ${SHOW_OPTION} condition YES or NO.

```
if ("$SHOW_OPTION" == ("NO")) {
     properties([ //No USER INPUT passed
       ])
else
{
     properties([
       parameters([ string(name: 'USER_INPUT_VALUE', defaultValue: 'mydefault']")
     ])
}
```

Later Jenikinsfile calls a shell script as ONE Liner which assigns a shell variable like below, When SHOW_OPTION is NO, I am assigning the hardcoded value, else actual USER value,

```
if [ ${SHOW_OPTION} == "NO" ]; then TARGET='"NO_USER_VALUE"'; else TARGET=$USER_INPUT_VALUE; fi;
```

But when SHOW_OPTION is NO, build complains as `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: USER_INPUT_VALUE for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Why script is validating else part here as it is not applicable. Is there any way to skip this validation in shell script.

Note: When I run one liner on regular shell I dont see any issue (verified with echo $?)

Comment: Why are you using properrties? are global var an option for you? do you have a hello world or snippet ready to use?

Comment: You cannot add conditionals at parameter definition level in declarative pipeline

Answer (score 1):

## declarative pipeline

- Don't forget to start the bash script with `#!/bin/bash`
- Build parameters are not sent to shell script.
- Only jenkins env vars are sent to the shell script.

```
def scriptContent = """#!/bin/bash

echo "script arguments"
echo "\$@" 

#echo "env variables passed to script"
#env 

if [ \$SHOW_OPTION == "NO" ]; then TARGET=\'"NO_USER_VALUE"\'; else TARGET=\$USER_INPUT_VALUE; fi;

echo "shell result:"
echo TARGET="\$TARGET"
""";

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        SHOW_OPTION="NO"
    }    
    
    stages {
        stage('Setup parameters') {
            steps {
                
                //simulating your shell script
                writeFile(file: "script.sh" , text: scriptContent) 
                
                script { 
                    if ("$SHOW_OPTION" == ("NO")) {
                         println "no parameters are configured"
                    }else{
                         properties([
                           parameters([
                                string(defaultValue: 'mydefault', name: 'USER_INPUT_VALUE')
                            ])  
                         ])
                    }
                }
                
                println "build params"
                println params
                //simulating your shell script
                sh "chmod +x script.sh"
                sh "./script.sh"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Result when SHOW_OPTION is "YES":**

[image]

**Result when SHOW_OPTION is "NO":**

[image]

> Note: The parameter should be deleted manually because when SHOW_OPTION=YES , the parameters was added to the pipeline. **Because of this, I advice to not configure dynamic parameters in the pipeline**. You could add the parameter in a standard way and compare if its value is null

## scripted pipeline

In case someone is using a scripted pipeline, this work as expected:

```
def SHOW_OPTION= "true";

node {

    if ("$SHOW_OPTION" == "NO") {
     println "no parameters"
    }else{
        properties(
            [
                parameters([
                        string(defaultValue: 'mydefault', name: 'USER_INPUT_VALUE')
                ])   
            ]
        )      
    }

    println params.USER_INPUT_VALUE
    
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the detailed reply. The target is to run the one shell command (in my case one liner of shell command ) with if and else in it. I want to run this script { 
                    if ("$SHOW_OPTION" == ("NO")) {
                         ... }
                }   in one shell command like if [ ${SHOW_OPTION} == "NO" ]; then TARGET='"NO_USER_VALUE"'; else TARGET=$USER_INPUT_VALUE; fi; I do not want to run script as a separate script file, but run INLINE inside the script {} block

Comment: I mean in your example "USER_INPUT_VALUE" is alway available right? Then script doesn't fail

Comment: pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        SHOW_OPTION="NO"
    }    
    stages {
      stage('Setup parameters') {
        steps {
          script { 
      sh 'if [ $SHOW_OPTION = "NO" ]; then TARGET="NO_USER_VALUE"; else TARGET=$USER_INPUT_VALUE; fi;'
      sh echo "TARGET=$TARGET"
          }
        }
      }
    }   
}
To run simple script like above